# android emulator do not start and still display word ANDROID

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

I am using the android emulator with eclipse but the problem that is when i start the emulator it freeze and still display the word ANDROID with no change

can anyone help me to fix this problem ???
and this is the

## logCat

```
10-21 14:55:18.623: I/DEBUG(33): debuggerd: Mar 27 2012 23:11:09
10-21 14:55:18.658: I/qemu-props(31): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
10-21 14:55:18.713: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
10-21 14:55:18.713: I/qemu-props(31): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=32m
10-21 14:55:18.934: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
10-21 14:55:18.934: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240
10-21 14:55:18.993: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
10-21 14:55:18.993: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
10-21 14:55:19.070: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
10-21 14:55:19.070: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=none
10-21 14:55:19.073: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..
10-21 14:55:19.073: I/qemu-props(31): exiting (4 properties set).
10-21 14:55:19.233: I/Vold(30): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
10-21 14:55:19.385: D/Vold(30): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
10-21 14:55:19.475: I/Netd(32): Netd 1.0 starting
10-21 14:55:20.065: E/Netd(32): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
10-21 14:55:20.065: E/Netd(32): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
10-21 14:55:24.582: D/AndroidRuntime(36): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
10-21 14:55:24.622: D/AndroidRuntime(36): CheckJNI is ON
10-21 14:55:25.436: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): SurfaceFlinger is starting
10-21 14:55:25.492: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
10-21 14:55:25.596: D/gralloc_goldfish(35): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): using (fd=10)
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): id           = 
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): xres         = 480 px
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): yres         = 800 px
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): xres_virtual = 480 px
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): yres_virtual = 1600 px
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): bpp          = 16
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): r            = 11:5
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): g            =  5:6
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): b            =  0:5
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): width        = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): height       = 123 mm (165.203247 dpi)
10-21 14:55:25.602: I/gralloc(35): refresh rate = 260.42 Hz
10-21 14:55:25.673: D/libEGL(35): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
10-21 14:55:25.692: D/libEGL(35): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): EGL informations:
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): # of configs : 8
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): vendor    : Android
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): extensions: EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer 
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): Client API: OpenGL ES
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): OpenGL informations:
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): vendor    : Android
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.4
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): extensions: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096 x 4096
10-21 14:55:25.826: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): flags = 00040000
10-21 14:55:25.852: W/SurfaceFlinger(35): hwcomposer module not found
10-21 14:55:27.292: D/libEGL(65): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
10-21 14:55:27.362: D/libEGL(65): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-21 14:55:27.587: D/gralloc_goldfish(65): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-21 14:55:28.164: I/(37): ServiceManager: 0xf958
10-21 14:55:28.263: I/AudioFlinger(37): Loaded primary audio interface from LEGACY Audio HW HAL (audio)
10-21 14:55:28.263: I/AudioFlinger(37): Using 'LEGACY Audio HW HAL' (audio.primary) as the primary audio interface
10-21 14:55:28.263: D/AudioHardwareInterface(37): setMode(NORMAL)
10-21 14:55:28.447: I/CameraService(37): CameraService started (pid=37)
10-21 14:55:28.699: D/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(37): Emulated camera list: 
10-21 14:55:28.746: D/EmulatedCamera_FakeCamera(37): Initialize: Fake camera is facing none
10-21 14:55:28.793: V/EmulatedCamera_Factory(37): 1 cameras are being emulated. Fake camera ID is 0
10-21 14:55:28.838: I/ARMAssembler(65): generated scanline__00000077:03010102_00000A01_00000000 [  9 ipp] (30 ins) at [0x409a51e8:0x409a5260] in 36130839 ns
10-21 14:55:28.873: I/ARMAssembler(65): generated scanline__00000077:03545402_00000A01_00000000 [ 31 ipp] (52 ins) at [0x409a5268:0x409a5338] in 6793919 ns
10-21 14:55:29.068: I/AudioFlinger(37): AudioFlinger's thread 0x10fe0 ready to run
10-21 14:55:29.073: W/AudioFlinger(37): Thread AudioOut_1 cannot connect to the power manager service
10-21 14:55:29.123: W/AudioFlinger(37): Thread AudioOut_1 cannot connect to the power manager service
10-21 14:55:29.243: I/AudioPolicyService(37): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
10-21 14:55:47.112: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(36): Profiling disabled.
10-21 14:55:48.342: I/Zygote(36): Preloading classes...
10-21 14:55:48.779: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 36K, 81% free 408K/2048K, paused 69ms+44ms
10-21 14:55:50.192: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 77% free 472K/2048K, paused 58ms+3ms
10-21 14:55:52.003: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 76% free 508K/2048K, paused 61ms+59ms
10-21 14:55:53.773: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 74% free 535K/2048K, paused 59ms+69ms
10-21 14:55:54.858: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 72% free 575K/2048K, paused 68ms+4ms
10-21 14:55:57.183: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 71% free 601K/2048K, paused 42ms+4ms
10-21 14:56:02.243: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 30K, 69% free 634K/2048K, paused 208ms+68ms
10-21 14:56:03.483: D/TextLayoutCache(36): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
10-21 14:56:04.083: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
10-21 14:56:06.523: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
10-21 14:56:06.573: D/MtpDeviceJNI(36): register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
10-21 14:56:06.693: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
10-21 14:56:06.752: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
10-21 14:56:06.764: W/MediaProfiles(36): could not find media config xml file
10-21 14:56:07.003: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher
10-21 14:56:07.052: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub
10-21 14:56:07.723: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 68% free 674K/2048K, paused 49ms+11ms
10-21 14:56:17.053: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 216K, 53% free 970K/2048K, paused 600ms
10-21 14:56:19.553: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 44K, 50% free 1025K/2048K, paused 59ms+7ms
10-21 14:56:22.693: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 49% free 1054K/2048K, paused 6ms+60ms
10-21 14:56:26.273: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 47% free 1102K/2048K, paused 8ms+60ms
10-21 14:56:28.338: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 43% free 1169K/2048K, paused 41ms+114ms
10-21 14:56:31.913: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 30% free 1447K/2048K, paused 44ms+93ms
10-21 14:56:32.263: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$CharCount
10-21 14:56:32.732: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.text.method.WordIterator$1
10-21 14:56:34.956: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 28% free 1482K/2048K, paused 68ms+63ms
10-21 14:56:37.202: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 27% free 1504K/2048K, paused 109ms+81ms
10-21 14:56:43.169: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)
10-21 14:56:43.267: D/dalvikvm(36): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libchromium_net.so 0x0, skipping init
10-21 14:56:46.233: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 25% free 1553K/2048K, paused 65ms+50ms
10-21 14:56:49.036: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.widget.EdgeGlow
10-21 14:56:52.633: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 23% free 1582K/2048K, paused 109ms+18ms
10-21 14:56:59.212: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 21% free 1627K/2048K, paused 94ms+21ms
10-21 14:56:59.982: E/PhonePolicy(36): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
10-21 14:57:01.882: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 33K, 20% free 1649K/2048K, paused 63ms+215ms
10-21 14:57:04.853: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 19% free 1677K/2048K, paused 129ms+31ms
10-21 14:57:06.868: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 17% free 1708K/2048K, paused 10ms+50ms
10-21 14:57:10.253: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 16% free 1734K/2048K, paused 470ms+30ms
10-21 14:57:12.463: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 14% free 1762K/2048K, paused 68ms+64ms
10-21 14:57:14.973: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 12% free 1817K/2048K, paused 67ms+112ms
10-21 14:57:17.073: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 11% free 1833K/2048K, paused 79ms+45ms
10-21 14:58:06.766: I/System(36): Loaded time zone names for  in 47518ms (47180ms in ICU)
10-21 14:58:43.909: I/System(36): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 37082ms (36678ms in ICU)
10-21 14:58:45.473: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 324K, 16% free 1950K/2307K, paused 58ms+162ms
10-21 14:58:47.273: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 13% free 2011K/2307K, paused 64ms+67ms
10-21 14:58:50.708: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 51K, 12% free 2043K/2307K, paused 67ms+69ms
10-21 14:58:53.003: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 11% free 2074K/2307K, paused 13ms+54ms
10-21 14:58:55.225: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 10% free 2091K/2307K, paused 52ms+174ms
10-21 14:58:57.722: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 9% free 2113K/2307K, paused 158ms+136ms
10-21 14:58:58.116: I/Zygote(36): ...preloaded 2297 classes in 189775ms.
10-21 14:58:59.318: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 9% free 2117K/2307K, paused 84ms+29ms
10-21 14:58:59.318: I/Zygote(36): Preloading resources...
10-21 14:58:59.982: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d7 (res/drawable-hdpi/spinner_black_16.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:00.269: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d8 (res/drawable-hdpi/spinner_black_20.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:00.544: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d9 (res/drawable-hdpi/spinner_black_48.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:00.932: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804da (res/drawable-hdpi/spinner_black_76.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:02.246: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 8% free 2202K/2371K, paused 139ms+55ms
10-21 14:59:02.358: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e8 (res/drawable-hdpi/spinner_white_16.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:02.595: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e9 (res/drawable-hdpi/spinner_white_48.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:02.842: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804ea (res/drawable-hdpi/spinner_white_76.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:04.143: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 7% free 2270K/2435K, paused 102ms+64ms
10-21 14:59:04.483: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080096 (res/drawable-hdpi/toast_frame.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:04.673: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805d0 (res/drawable-hdpi/toast_frame_holo.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:06.137: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 7% free 2339K/2499K, paused 98ms+115ms
10-21 14:59:06.333: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080106 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:06.583: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080105 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:06.793: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080104 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:07.053: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080103 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:08.583: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 7% free 2391K/2563K, paused 89ms+116ms
10-21 14:59:08.755: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080102 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:09.013: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080101 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:09.283: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ff (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:09.373: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fe (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:09.533: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fd (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:11.163: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 8% free 2438K/2627K, paused 74ms+105ms
10-21 14:59:11.343: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fc (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:11.565: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fb (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:11.673: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fa (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
10-21 14:59:11.745: W/Zygote(36): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f6 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on_disable_focused.png) that varies with configuration!!
```

Comment: Have you tried `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`? Also, instead of running the emulated virtual device as-is, try changing the screen size. You can do this by clicking the **Start** button in **Android Device Chooser** screen, then define the screen size in **Launch Options** screen. Ensure **Scale** ratio is less than 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Virtual Android Machine, VirtualBox for example, and connect it to Eclipse like this:

```
[path_to_adb.exe] connect [device_ip]
```

in my case, i do this commands to connect:

```
D:
cd android\sdk-d\platform-tools
adb.exe connect 192.168.56.101
```

To download "ready to use" .ova file, you can visit [this](http://androvm.org/blog/download/) page.

Comment: so their is no solution to my problem with keeping on the google android emulator ???